# Bug in GnuWin32 port of mkdir?

Tags: gnuwin32

I seem to have come across a wierd behaviour of GnuWin32's mkdir (from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)):

```
C:\sandbox>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE" --verbose -p Q:/scratch/foo/bar
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE: created directory `Q:/scratch'
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE: created directory `Q:/scratch/foo'
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE: created directory `Q:/scratch/foo/bar'
```

In the above, the current drive is C and the target drive is Q.
As expected, the hierarchy gets created in `Q:/scratch/foo/bar`

Now, almost the same example but the current and the target drives are both C.

```
C:\sandbox>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE" --verbose -p C:/scratch/foo/bar
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE: created directory `C:/scratch'
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE: created directory `C:/scratch/foo'
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mkdir.EXE: created directory `C:/scratch/foo/bar'
```

mkdir's output looks right and very predictable.
However, nothing really gets created at `C:/scratch/foo/bar`. Rather, the directory hierarchy gets created using the current directory as a root, i.e. what gets created is `C:/sandbox/scratch/foo/bar`

Can anyone confirm ? Is this a bug ?
I would look at the source code if I had the time but....

Does anyone know of a more recent version of CoreUtils than 5.3.0 that's been ported to Win32 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a small bug indeed. It seems GnuWin32's port doesn't like the forward slash after the colon following the drive letter. Using backslashes it behaves correctly with both

```
C:\sandbox> mkdir --verbose -p Q:\scratch/foo/bar
```

and

```
C:\sandbox> mkdir --verbose -p C:\scratch/foo/bar
```

But (as reported) when using forward slashes, it only behaves correctly with

```
C:\sandbox> mkdir --verbose -p Q:/scratch/foo/bar
```

(**in the above, note the target is on a different drive than the prompt**) but not with

```
C:\sandbox> mkdir --verbose -p C:/scratch/foo/bar
```

(**in the above, note the target is on the same drive as the prompt**)

The really old mkdir port from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) has the correct behaviour all the time. That's the only working alternative I could find.